# Use generating functions to prove that the number of partitions of a positive integer n into parts, each part at most 2, is [n/2] + 1

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs

Use generating functions to prove that the number of partitions of a
positive integer n into parts, each part at most 2, is ⌊n/2 ⌋ + 1

What I have:

since each part is at most 2,
I have p(x) = (1+x+x^2+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)
Which is equal to $\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}$
Using fraction decomposition I have $ \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((-1)^n + 1 + n)x^n$ . Now I don't know know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(x)=(\underbrace{1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots}_{\text{#parts of size 1}})(\underbrace{1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots}_{\text{#parts of size 2}})$$
There's no need to simplify $P(x)$ here. Products of monomials straddling both factors and evaluating to $x^n$ are $x^n\cdot1,x^{n-2}\cdot x^2,\dots,x^{n\bmod2}\cdot x^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$, so the coefficient of $x^n$ in $P(x)$ is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$, as required.

Comment: sorry i don't really understand your explanation, is there any way you can elaborate or expand